# Custom ios camera shutter

Tags: ios, camera, avfoundation

Is there any ready custom iris/shutter view for ios camera?

I'm going to implement camera app using AVFoundataion, and there is no shutter in it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13370114/shutter-animation-avfoundation-iphone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, if you are purely using AVFoundation for capture, you need to build it yourself.

The alternative is using `UIImagePickerController` with a custom `cameraOverlayView` if your camera app is simple enough.

Answer (score 0):

But UImagePickerController is not working correctly .because shutter is not opening in interrupted call or background apps.