# Shutter animation AVFoundation iphone

Tags: ios, camera

I am trying to replicate iPhone Camera app default shutter animation.

Maybe anyone has tried doing that and have some hints to share?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Well, I found this somewhere:

```
     CATransition *shutterAnimation = [CATransition animation];
     [shutterAnimation setDelegate:self];
     [shutterAnimation setDuration:0.6];

     shutterAnimation.timingFunction = UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut;
     [shutterAnimation setType:@"cameraIris"];
     [shutterAnimation setValue:@"cameraIris" forKey:@"cameraIris"];
     CALayer *cameraShutter = [[CALayer alloc]init];
     [cameraShutter setBounds:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 425.0)];
     [self.layer addSublayer:cameraShutter];
     [self.layer addAnimation:shutterAnimation forKey:@"cameraIris"];
```

It's the default iPhone camera shutter animation.

Comment: It's a pity that "cameraIris" is not a public documented value for [CATransition type]. Does anyone has an experience on whether this will be rejected by Apple?

Comment: Nice ! timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];

Answer (score 2):

And in Swift 3.0...

```
let shutterAnimation = CATransition.init()
shutterAnimation.duration = 0.6
shutterAnimation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction.init(name: 
kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)
shutterAnimation.type = "cameraIris"
shutterAnimation.setValue("cameraIris", forKey: "cameraIris")

let shutterLayer = CALayer.init()
shutterLayer.bounds = self.view.bounds
self.view.layer.addSublayer(shutterLayer)
self.view.layer.add(shutterAnimation, forKey: "cameraIris")
```